Indented JSON in console output
This question is about the Console sink:
When using a format string like "Hello World\n{@environment}" and e.g. passing an anonymous object like new { A = "a", B = 1 }, the standard output is as follows:
Hello World
{"A" = "a", "B" = 1}

Is there a built-in way to use indentation for automatically serialized template argument objects?
I'm looking for output similar to this:
Hello World
{
  "A" = "a",
  "B" = 1
}

To clarify: I don’t want to do custom json formatting but instead change the output of the json formatter that internally is used by the Console sink when serializing „deconstruction“ arguments (@ template operator).
